# Steps to connect IBM MQ Queue from .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ classes from NuGet repository (amqmdnetstd.dll version 9.1.4) using below code to create a connection but getting error "CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'destinationArray')"

```
var xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            var cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, WebsphereMqHost);
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, WebsphereMqPort);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, WebsphereMqChannel);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, WebsphereMqQueueManager);
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

            var conn = cf.CreateConnection();
            var sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            var queue = sess.CreateQueue(QueueName);
            var consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(queue);
```

Comment: This [thread on MQSeries.net](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=77072&sid=b3392b0a0d00476e300b968bcb2a72dc) seems to describe the same situation.  The poster fixed it by backing off to 9.1.3.  I would suggest trying the new 9.2.0.0 LTS version (this rolled up all features/updates that were present in 9.1.5).  If it doesn't work in 9.2.0.0, then try 9.1.5, if it does not work there, then go with 9.1.3 and open a case with IBM about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The above error seems to be a bug in the code and is fixed in [APAR IT31572](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT31572)
and is part of MQ v9.1.5 CD or MQ v9.2 LTS. So using 9.1.5/9.2 should solve the problem.

Comment: This APAR lists fixed in 9.1.5, but it is not present on the 9.1 CDS fix list page or on 9.2 CDS fix list, can you update those?